# Creating a sudoku. Should I use a while statement for this code?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm making a sudoku in Windows Form Application.

I have 81 textboxes and I have named them all textBox1a, textBox1b... textBox2a, textBox2b...

I want to make it so that if any of the textboxes, in any of the rows, is equal to any other textbox in the same row, then both will get the background color red while the textboxes are equal.

I tried using this code just for test:

```
private void textBox1a_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        while (textBox1a.Text == textBox1b.Text)
        {
            textBox1a.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            textBox1b.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
```

It didn't work, and I don't know where I should put all this code, I know I shouldn't have it in the textboxes.

Should I use a code similar to this or is it totally wrong?

Comment: What exactly do you expect your example code to do?

Comment: No, not a while-loop.  A for-loop with if statements probably.  A two dimensional array should probably be employed somewhere in your code.

Comment: 1. Implement a look up collection. 
2. Let each item of collection be a container containing - textbox & row number. 
3. Whenever a textbox is updated, traverse through the collection looking for text     boxes with same row number & same text. if you find some update the color.

Comment: Text change event requires a tab or key press before it fires. Did you try to tab out of the textbox? Debug and make sure the code reaches this snippet.

Comment: This has two problems, 1) its an infinite loop since you lock up the UI thread there is no possible way the two textboxes will change, and 2) its a cross-threading violation. Just remove the `while` and replace with `if`, but you'll need to do it for all textboxes in that row. I'm guessing 1/2/3 is the row, and a,b,c is the column? You should construct a 2-d array of all the textboxes, it'll make it a lot easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

You want to iterate over the collection of text boxes just once, comparing it to those that haven't yet been compared against. If you have your textboxes in an array (let's call it textBoxes), and know which one was just changed (e.g. from the textChanged handler), you could do:

```
void highlightDuplicates(int i) // i is the index of the box that was changed
{
   int iVal = textBoxes[i].Text;
   for (int j = 0; j < 82; j++) 
   {
      // don't compare to self
      if (i == j) return;

      if (textBoxes[j].Text == iVal)
      {
         textBoxes[i].BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
         textBoxes[j].BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
      }
   }
}
```

If you wanted to get fancier, you could put your data in something like: `Dictionary<int, TextBox>`, where the key is the value and the TextBox is a reference to the text box with that value. Then you can quickly test for duplicate values with Dictionary.Contains() and color the matching text box by getting its value.

Answer (score 0):

I think your current code would result in an infinite loop. The textboxes' values can't change while you are still in the event handler, so that loop would never exit.

If all of your boxes are named according to one convention, you could do something like this. More than one input can use the same handler, so you can just assign this handler to all the boxes.

*The following code is not tested and may contain errors*

```
private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
     var thisBox = sender as TextBox;
     //given name like "textBox1a"
     var boxNumber = thisBox.Name.SubString(7,1);
     var boxLetter = thisBox.Name.SubString(8,1);

     //numbers (horizontal?)
     for(int i = 1; i<=9; i++){
          if(i.ToString() == boxNumber)
               continue; //don't compare to self
          var otherBox = Page.FindControl("textBox" + i + boxLetter) as TextBox;

          if (otherBox.Text == thisBox.Text)
          {
               thisBox.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
               otherBox.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
          }
     }

     //letters (vertical?)
     for(int i = 1; i<=9; i++){
          var j = ConvertNumberToLetter(i); //up to you how to do this
          if(j == boxLetter)
               continue; //don't compare to self
          var otherBox = Page.FindControl("textBox" + boxNumber + j) as TextBox;

          if (otherBox.Text == thisBox.Text)
          {
               thisBox.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
               otherBox.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will be more effective if create an Array (or a List) of Integers and compare them in memory, against compare them in UI (User Interface).

For instance, you could:
1) Create an Array of 81 integers.
2) Everytime the user input a new number, you search for it in that Array. If found, set the textbox as RED, otherwise, add the new value to that array.
3) The ENTER event may be allocated fot the entire Textboxes (utilize the Handles keyword with all Textboxes; like handles Text1.enter, Text2.enter, Text3.enter ... and so forth)

Something like:

```
int[] NumbersByUser = new int[81];

 Private Sub Textbox1.Enter(sender as object, e as EventArgs) handles Textbox1.Enter, Textbox2.Enter, Textbox3.enter ...

 int UserEntry = Convert.ToInt32(Sender.text);
 int ValorSelecionado = Array.Find(NumbersByUser, Z => (Z == UserEntry));
 if (ValorSelecionado > 0) {
    Sender.forecolor = Red;
  } 
  else
  {
  NumbersByUser(Index) = UserEntry;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should have a 2 dimensional array of numbers (could be one dimensional, but 2 makes more sense) let's assume its called `Values`. I suggest that you have each textbox have a incrementing number (starting top left, going right, then next row). Now you can do the following:

All TextBox Changed events can point to the same function. The function then takes the tag to figure out the position in the 2dim array. (X coordinate is TAG % 9 and Y coordinate is TAG / 9)

In the callback you can loop over the textboxes and colorize all boxes as you like. First do the "check row" loop (pseudo code)

```
var currentTextBox = ((TextBox)sender)
var x = ((int)currentTextBox.Tag) % 9
var y = ((int)currentTextBox.Tag) / 9
// First assign the current value to the backing store
Values[currentTextBox] = int.parse(currentTextBox.Text)

// assuming variable x holding the column and y holding the row of current box
// Array to hold the status of a number (is it already used?)
bool isUsed[9] = {false, false, ...}
for(int col = 0; col <= 9; i++)
{
    // do not compare with self
    if(col == x) continue;
    isUsed[textBox] = true;
}
// now we have the status of all other boxes
if( isUsed[Values[x,y]] ) currentTextBox.Background = Red else currentTextBox.Background = Green
// now repeat the procedure for the column iterating the rows and for the blocks
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a dynamic approach to this. Consider each board item as a cell (this would be it's own class). The class would contain a numeric value and other properties that could be useful (i.e. a list of possible values).

You would then create 3 collections of the cells, these would be:

1. A collection of rows of 9 cells (for tracking each row)
2. A collection of columns of 9 cells (for tracking each column)
3. A collection of 3x3 cells

These collections would share references - each cell object would appear once in each collection. Each cell could also contain a reference to each of the 3 collections.

Now, when a cell value is changed, you can get references to each of the 3 collections and then apply a standard set of Sudoku logic against any of those collections.

You then have some display logic that can walk the boards of cells and output to the display (your View) your values.

Enjoy - this is a fun project.